# How to pass a single value from List Item with multiple TextViews when it's fetched from Json?

Tags: android, json, listview, listitem

I have fetched values from a Json file into a ListView , each item in list view contains many TextViews (and their values are assigned Json file) , I wish to pass separate values of all the TextViews present in a single ListItem to another activity . Let me know that how to do so .

Thanks

And this is the code and when I'm passing a value then instead of passing a single string it passes all and displays them in a json form on second screen . :

```
 import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Other extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ListView lv;


    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxx";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        contactList = new ArrayList<>();

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        new GetContacts().execute();

   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

           String value = lv.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString();



           String author = value.concat(String.valueOf(R.id.author));
           // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
           Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Display.class);
           // sending data to new activity
           i.putExtra("author",author );
           startActivity(i);

       }
       }
   );


    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Other.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("articles");

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                         JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        String auth = c.getString("author");
                        String title = c.getString("title");
                        String des = c.getString("description");
                        String ur = c.getString("url");
                        String img = c.getString("urlToImage");
                        String dat = c.getString("publishedAt");


                        // tmp hash map for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put("author", auth);
                        contact.put("title", title);
                        contact.put("description", des);
                        contact.put("url", ur);
                        contact.put("urlToImage", img);
                        contact.put("publishedAt", dat);





                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);
                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    Other.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"author",
                    "title" , "urlToImage" , "url" , "publishedAt"}, new int[]{R.id.author, R.id.title , R.id.urlToImage , R.id.url , R.id.date});

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
 }


    }
}
```

This is what appears when I run it :

[Screenshot of what happens after clicking a list item .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kn5xg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a ListAdapter, you populate it with `contactList` which is a `List` of `Map`.
The problem lies in this line

```
String value = lv.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString();
```

Here, you get the item using `getItem(position)`. This will return you a single element from `contactList` which would be a `Map`. But you are calling `toString` over it, this will convert the `Map` to `String` which you don't want.

Instead, cast you Item into a `Map`.
In your case, do this.

```
HashMap<String, String> value = (HashMap) lv.getAdapter().getItem(position);
```

Now you can get single values using

```
String author = value.get("author");
```

Put them to your intent

```
i.putExtra("author", author);
```

Similarly, get more values from `value.get()` and put all of them in intent, if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely pass multiple values using the Intent object. Think of it as collection of key value pairs.

You can add more values similar to i.putExtra(“author”, author).

Answer (score 0):

One good way to pass a list is to bundle them pass it using an intent

On passing Activity

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle.putString(key, value);
mIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
```

On Receiving Activity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String value = extras.getString(key)
```

This way you could bundle all of your your data. My suggestion for the same would be **model your data and try sending your object** through bundle intent.